# UISearchBar as a subview to UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UITableView` that has a subview `UISearchBar` attached via the Interface Builder. When `- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` is called, I set `searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES` and call `[searchBar sizeToFit]` to actually show the scope bar of the search bar.

The problem is, that the first cell of my table view gets covered by the appearing scope bar. How can I refit the table view correctly?

Comment: Can you try with `sizeToFit`, it is a UIView class, I am not sure if it runs or not

Comment: I'm confused. If you want to show the scope bar why are you calling `searchBar.showsScopeBar = NO`? Is this a work around of some sort?

Comment: Ah. Typo. I've corrected my original post. The search bar is invisible at launch time and shall only show up when the search bar is used.

Comment: No. I made the scope bar persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed it. I had my UISearchBar side-by-side with my UITableView in my xib file, and was adding it as a subview of the table view in code. I switched to doing this in the xib instead and all is well.